# Custom Field data missing in export

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, profile, export

For an event we wanted to aks for more information so i set up a set of custom fields.

[image: Custom fields set]

I added this to a profile and added some more fields

[image: Profile with custom fields an other data]

I added the profile to an event registration. If a user registers, all fileds are shown an the user can add data in all fields and they are shown in the confirmation and thank you- page.
[image: Confirmationpage]

But in the Confirmation email [image]
some date of the custom fields Projektgebiet - Quartier(Participant), Projektträger(Participant) and Einwilligung(Participant)are missing.
I also exported the data and in the .csv data and even the fieldlabels of the above mentioned fields are missing.

I would be happy of any help and solution suggestion.
We are using Civicrm with drupal.
Thank you